# Api Climatempo C#

Tags: c#, api, aplicação-web

Boa tarde, estou fazendo uma aplicação web para faculdade onde preciso consumir uma API de ClimaTempo em C#, no meu código, estou passando como parâmetro o código da cidade e fazendo a requisição para o:
https://advisor.climatempo.com.br

Essa é a minha URL de requisição no final:
http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/weather/locale/3480/current?token=866474fc3c51b2f4229db9d8f11648de

Até ai tudo bem, criei os campos na VIEW para informar o código da cidade e no Controller a busca:

```
 public ActionResult PrevisaoTempo(UsuarioCliente usuario)
 {

            string url = "http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/weather/locale/"+usuario.Cod+"/current?token=866474fc3c51b2f4229db9d8f11648de";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
            json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

            usuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioCliente>(json);

            TempData["Usuario"] = usuario;

            return RedirectToAction("Create", "PrevisaoTempo");
  }
```

A questão é que, ele trás o JSON todo certinho e eu até consigo mostrar na view as informações pra trás de "DATA" do JSON. Porém depois de DATA, vira NULL depois de passar pelo DeserializeObject e assim os campos de temperature e sensation chegam null's na VIEW, conseguem me ajudar nisso? Muito obrigado!

No caso eu só quero trazer a temperature e sensation do vetor DATA
Classe UsuarioCliente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjetoCotacao2.Models
{
    [Table("UsuarioClientes")]
    public class UsuarioCliente
    {

        [Key]
        public int IDUsuarioCliente { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido!")]
        public string Email_Cliente { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        [Display(Name = "Login do usuário")]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Senha")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public string SenhaCliente { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Confirmação Senha")]
        [Compare("SenhaCliente", ErrorMessage = "Os campos não coincidem!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [NotMapped]

        public string ConfirmacaoSenha { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CPF")]

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public string CPF_Cliente { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = " No mínimo 3 caracteres")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public string Nome_Cliente { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório!")]
        public string Telefone_Cliente { get; set; }

        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Localidade { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string temperature { get; set; }
        public string sensation { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: Poste a class UsuarioCliente

Comment: Atualizei o post

Comment: sua classe está bem diferente do que retorna o json

Comment: A classe pertence a um projeto maior, a API do climatempo é parte do projeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando a documentação em http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/doc/index.html, é possível ver que sua classe não tem as propriedades com o mesmo nome retornado no json.

A estrutura da classe básica que atende a documentação e resultado retornado seria assim:

```
public class Data
{
    public int temperature { get; set; }
    public string wind_direction { get; set; }
    public int wind_velocity { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public int sensation { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioCliente
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Fiz um exemplo funcional para demonstrar o resultado aqui: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jbbfgo)

Answer (score 2):

Sua classe `UsuarioCliente` não está as mesma propriedades do `Json`. Para garantir o mapeamento de todas propriedade use esse site: http://json2csharp.com/.

Sua classe deve está dessa forma:

```
public class Data
{
        public int temperature { get; set; }
        public string wind_direction { get; set; }
        public double wind_velocity { get; set; }
        public double humidity { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public int sensation { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
}
public class UsuarioCliente
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }  
        public int IDUsuarioCliente { get; set; }
        public string Email_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }        
        public string SenhaCliente { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmacaoSenha { get; set; }
        public string CPF_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Nome_Cliente { get; set; }  
        public string Telefone_Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Localidade { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, vou testar com essa modelagem!

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado!